# How to communicate two classes?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I want to let two classes communicate with each other. I want to use a dictionary to be able to add items. I've simplified my pattern to solve it easily. How to use dictionary to add a new item.

I want to generate only one instance of `MyClass`. That is important. This is a kind of a trick...

```
public interface IHost
{

}

public class MyClass:IHost
{
   public Dictionary<int,string>; dic { get; set;}

   public MyClass()
   {
       dic =  new Dictionary<int,string>();
   }
}

public class  MyClass2 : IHost
{
    public MyClass()
    {

    }

    public void Save()
    {
      dic.Add(1,"vxcvcx");
    }
}
```

Error that I get:

> The name 'dic' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Please clarify your question (though technically, you didn't ask one). What exactly are you trying to do? Can you post code that will actually compile (with or without the line you are saying you are getting an error on).

Comment: @StevenJeuris: Not everyone has English as primary language.

Comment: @jgauffin: ... but everyone _can_ have a built in spelling checker in their browser, and at least be consistent with their spelling errors. If you don't know how to write 'communicate' don't write it differently from time to time, look it up. I don't speak native English either, and still look up words from time to time. P.s.: It's not like the rest of the question indicated any effort. It seems the language is quite representative of the effort.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: True. You should have written that elaborate description in the first comment.

Comment: Put the function "Save" into "MyClass".

Comment: @StevenJeuris:why do you spend too time to write unsufficient paragraph? Why do you think how to solve this problem?i have worked 10-12 hours per day. my brain is down.PLease be sufficient:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a base class instead of an interface:

```
abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public Dictionary<int,string> dic { get; set; }

    public MyBaseClass()
    {
        dic = new Dictionary<int, string>(5);
    }

    public void Add(int key, string value)
    {
        dic.Add(key, value);
    }
}

public class MyClass1 : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyClass1():base()
    {          
    }        
}

public class MyClass2 : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyClass2():base()
    {

    }

    public void Save()
    {
        Add(1, "somevalue");
    }
}
```

Comment: Going with the requirement to have only one instance of MyClass, which I assume to mean only one dictionary, it'd be worth marking `dic` as static and initialising in a static constructor...

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the `MyClass` as a constructor variable to class2:

```
public class MyClass:IHost
{
   public Dictionary<int,string> dic { get; set;}

   public MyClass()
   {
       dic =  new Dictionary<int,string>();
   }

   public void Add(int key, string value)
   {
       dic.Add(key, value);
   }
}

public class  MyClass2 : IHost
{
    MyClass1 _class1;

    public MyClass2(MyClass1 instance)
    {
        _class1 = instance;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
      _class1.Add(1,"vxcvcx");
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a semicolon too much on line 3.

Comment: @vidstige: Thanks. The original code in the question (which I edited was HTML encoded)

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. MyClass2 needs a reference to an instance of MyClass1, then it can call `someMyClass1.dic.Add()`?
2. MyClass2 needs a reference to the dictionary in the the instance of MyClass1, as then the call to `dic.Add()` will work as it will have its `dic` set to the value of the MyClass1's `dic`.
3. MyClass2 needs to derive from MyClass1, then it is a more specialised type of MyClass1 and can access all public and protected members as if they were defined on it.

Answer (score 0):

Make MyClass1 singleton and access the dic variable from MyClass 2...Am I understood the scenario correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to address the obvious problem.

```
public Dictionary<int,string>; dic { get; set;}
```

should be

```
public Dictionary<int,string> dic;
```

The following code is not going to work, you have to define a **Dictionary** variable within MyClass2, for this code to work.

```
public class  MyClass2 : IHost   {       public MyClass()       {          }          public void Save()       {         dic.Add(1,"vxcvcx");       }   }
```

If the author updates the question, and actually explains what they are trying to achieve, I will update my answer.

I should add...the **MyClass** class is not required, the dictionary should be create in **MyClass2**